# Open options page of addon using `simple-prefs` from content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an addon using [`simple-prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs). The addon modifies some webpages using [`PageMod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod).

I would like to add a link to these webpages, that will open the addon options. Basically, what I need, is a Firefox version of [`chrome.extension.getURL('options.html');`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL) used in Chrome.

I have tried some old methods. For example using URL like this: `addons://detail/ADDON_ID/preferences`. Or [this method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Inline_Options#Resources) from official documentation. But none of them seem to work.

How do I do that? Is it even possible?

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/html-options

Comment: @Noitidart No. My addon uses SDK, is built using JPM and the options page is generated by `simple-prefs` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you can't open it directly from the content script. You'll have to send a message from your content script to your extension using the [port API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/port), which would look something like this in your content script:

```
self.port.emit("openPrefs");
```

In your add-on module where you have the reference to your PageMod object (I assume it's saved in the pageMod variable) you'd then open the preferences page using the (undocumented) sdk/preferences/utils module:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var { open } = require("sdk/preferences/utils");
pageMod.port.on("openPrefs", function() {
  open({ id: self.id });
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

For the future reference, how can I learn about the undocumented features in Firefox SDK? Where did you learn it?

Comment: I am a lot in the #jetpack channel on irc.mozilla.org, where developers also give tips if you have issues and they are around. Further I look at the source code (https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/).